# How Do I Dynamically Add Child Nodes To WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have this students list. I want to dynamically add hundreds of child nodes to my Tree View. I can add root items but not not child nodes. How do I do that?

My Code-

```
        public List<MyItem> Items { get; private set; }

        public class MyItem
        {
            public string Student { get; set; }
            public string Course { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
        }

        List<MyItem> list1 = new List<MyItem>();

            list1.Add(new MyItem()
            {
                Student = "Pradip Mhatre",
                Course = "Diploma",
                Location = "Mumbai"
            });

trvStudents.ItemsSource = list1;
```

XAML:

```
            <TreeView Name="trvStudents"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Student}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Course}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Location}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection, not List. That way, when you add or remove items, the tree will be notified of the change and will update accordingly. You can add child nodes by giving MyItem a child collection of its own (let’s call it Children), and setting ItemsSource=“{Binding Children}” on your HierarchicalDataTemplate.

Comment: I tried ObservableCollection but it's not working bcz I use WPF Page, not Window.  @EdPlunkett

Comment: No, you’re wrong. That’s not why it isn’t working. Don’t make things up, you’ll only confuse yourself. Please show the code where you tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EdPlunkett. Can you please send me a link of an example tutorial of WPF Observable Collection where I can create 100s of child nodes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to google that yourself. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: I didn't found anything useful.

Comment: I gave you the answer in my first comment. If you have a problem applying it, post a question with a [complete example that reproduces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people request further information, provide the information they ask for.